# My uvlib default loop quits unexpectedly - why?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am developing a program which watches a UDP port for a "discovery" packet. When it gets the packet, it echoes the packet to the sender and then should wait for further commands from sender.

This is implemented using uvlib (based on uvlib documentation, example here: http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/networking.html#udp ). I initialize a receive socket (to await the discovery packet), and a broadcast socket (for replying to discovery). When UDP data comes in, the on_UDP_read callback is triggered. In this callback, I get the caller's IP and port, and send the echo packet.

All this works fine (the sending system receives the echoed packet); the problem is that the main loop (uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT) is supposed to keep running after the reply... however, it exits with a return code of zero. I can't simply start it again in a (kludge) loop, because then a new port is selected each time by the sending system (standard UDP behavior), so I can't (later) send the bulk data I want to send.

**The question:** why does the main loop halt, just as if I had issued the uv_stop command?

I'm wondering if my use of memory has a problem. The send buffer is allocated in the function like so: const uv_buf_t a[] . (Maybe this has to be done using malloc??)

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <uv.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "de_signals.h"

#define BUFFERLEN 65    // Maximum length of buffer
#define PORT 1024   // Port to watch

uv_loop_t *loop;
uv_udp_t send_socket;
uv_udp_t recv_socket;

//sem_t mutex;
//pthread_t t1;

int sockfd;  // socket definition for UDP
struct sockaddr_in servaddr; 

static void alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t* handle, size_t suggested_size, uv_buf_t* buf) {
  buf->base = malloc(suggested_size);
  buf->len = suggested_size;
}

//struct sockaddr_in si_DE, si_main;

void on_UDP_send(uv_udp_send_t* req, int status)
{
  printf("UDP send complete, status = %d\n", status);
  // the following is supposed to free the send buffer, but causes a segmentation fault
  //free(req);
  return;
}

void on_UDP_read(uv_udp_t *req, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t *buf, const struct sockaddr *addr, unsigned flags) {
    puts("UDP data detected");
    if (nread < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read error %s\n", uv_err_name(nread));
        uv_close((uv_handle_t*) req, NULL);
        free(buf->base);
        return;
    }

    char sender[17] = { 0 };
    uv_ip4_name((const struct sockaddr_in*) addr, sender, 16);
    fprintf(stderr, "Recv from %s\n", sender);

    struct sockaddr_in *sin = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr;
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    uint16_t port;
    port = htons (sin->sin_port);
    printf("port = %d \n",port);

    int sentBytes;
    char replybuf[60];

    uv_ip4_name((const struct sockaddr_in*) addr, sender, 16);
    fprintf(stderr, "Recv from %s\n", sender);
    for(int i=0;i<nread;i++){fprintf(stderr,"%02X ",buf->base[i]);}
    fprintf(stderr,"\n");

    puts("create discovery reply buf");
    char b[60];
    for(int i=0;i<60;i++) {b[i] = 0;}
    if((buf->base[0] & 0xFF) == 0xEF && (buf->base[1] & 0xFF) == 0xFE) {
    fprintf(stderr,"discovery packet detected\n");
    b[0] = 0xEF;
    b[1] = 0xFE;
    b[2] = 0x02;
    }
    if((buf->base[0] & 0xFF) == 0x53 && (buf->base[1] & 0xFF) == 0x3F) {
    fprintf(stderr, "STATUS INQUIRY detected\n");
    b[0] = 0x4F;
        b[1] = 0x4B;
    port = 1024; // temporary, until we have a better way
    sleep(1); // let LH get socket open
    }


////////////// reply ///////////////

    uv_udp_send_t send_req;

    puts("create discovery reply buf");

    const uv_buf_t a[]={{.base = b, .len=60}};

    for(int i=0;i<60;i++){fprintf(stderr,"%02X ",a[0].base[i]);}; 
    fprintf(stderr,"\n");

    puts("ready to send");


// Here we reply to sender, using sender's IP and port

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    struct hostent* hptr = gethostbyname(sender);
    if(!hptr) puts ("gethostbyname error");
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =     //INADDR_ANY; 
    ((struct in_addr*) hptr->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;

    uv_udp_send(&send_req, &send_socket, a, 1, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
     on_UDP_send);


   puts("reply issued");

   // free(buf->base);
    uv_udp_recv_stop(req);   // ???
    puts("returning from processing UDP packet");
    return;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() {
 int retcode;
 //while(1==1)  // this is a kludgy extra loop until we find out why uv_run halts.
 //{



  puts("starting");
    loop = uv_default_loop();

    uv_udp_init(loop, &recv_socket);
    struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", 1024, &recv_addr);
    uv_udp_bind(&recv_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, UV_UDP_REUSEADDR);
    uv_udp_recv_start(&recv_socket, alloc_buffer, on_UDP_read);

    uv_udp_init(loop, &send_socket);
    struct sockaddr_in broadcast_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr("0.0.0.0", 0, &broadcast_addr);
    uv_udp_bind(&send_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&broadcast_addr, 0);
    uv_udp_set_broadcast(&send_socket, 1); puts("wait for UDP handshake\n");

  // Creating socket file descriptor for UDP
  if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
      }


  puts("start main loop");
  retcode = uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

  fprintf(stderr,"Return code from uv_run loop = %d \n",retcode);
 //}
 puts("out of main loop");
  return retcode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out part of this.  First of all, "uvlib" is not the name of the package; "libuv" is.  Second, the reason the loop quits is because there is a uv_udp_recv_stop(req) instruction at the end of the on_read callback routine. libuv exits when there is no more work to do.

REMAINING PROBLEM: if you remove the uv_udp_recv_stop(req) instruction with the idea that maybe that will leave the loop running (as it should), the program crashes with a Segmentation Fault. I reported this to the libuv team (using Github issue reporting), and they were not helpful, because they disclaim any responsibility for the correctness of the example programs posted in their libuv repository in github. Interestingly, when you install libuv and run a check (i.e., run their tests), the tests related to UDP multicast all fail. This suggests to me that the libuv package does indeed have some bugs in the UDP area; I reported this, but I guess the libuv team has bigger fish to fry.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and found out that the reason for segmentation is that the on_read callback uses some pointers without checking if they are null. Check [this](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/2606#issuecomment-962743244) for detail.